# What is the problem with my code to generate presigned url using node?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

There is something wrong with the pre-signed url generated with this api.
When i use postman to upload a image with it  shows error

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
What is wrong with my code?

```
const _ = require('lodash'),
statusCode = require('../../../lib/statusCode'),
AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
config = require('config');
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: config.get('AWS.accessKeyId'), 
secretAccessKey: config.get('AWS.secretAccessKey') });

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

class Queries {

static async imageUpload() {

    // var s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
    try {
        const params = { Bucket: 'firelabs', Key: 'jpegsystems- 
  home.jpg' , ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control', 
    ContentType:'image/jpeg' };
        const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
        console.log(url);
        return url;
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
}
   module.exports = Queries;
```

Comment: You didn't update the secret key of AWS.

Comment: See line 4 and 5 of the code

Comment: You just got the secret key from the config and did nothing with it

Comment: i am getting it  by  using config.get('----')  in the aws.update function.

Comment: I see. My bad. You should indent your code in line 6. So it can be easy to read